# How to make many files public in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-cloud-storage, cloud, roles

I have 1000 files in Google Cloud Storage to make public, or in general a directory hierarchy.

In the Web UI, I can only seem to make one at a time public.

Is there some way to do this.

Comment: I found it.  You can run: gsutil ls to get a listing of files.  Then you can pipe the listing into xargs with gsutil setacl public-read *.  You can also do gsutil setdefacl public-read so that future uploaded files will be public

Answer (score 129):

Run `gsutil -m acl set -R -a public-read gs://bucket`

- The `-m` issues multiple requests at the same time.
- The `-R` issues requests for every object in your bucket.
- The `-a` issues requests for every version of every object.

See [`gsutil help acl`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl) for more info.

At the API layer [gsutil](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) issues the following HTTP request:

```
PUT /bucket/obj?acl HTTP/1.1
Host: storage.googleapis.com
x-goog-acl: public-read
```

You can see this by using the `-D` flag with `gsutil`:

```
gsutil -D setacl public-read gs://bucket/obj
```

Comment: Thanks for this !
Currently doc display 'gsutil acl set public-read gs://bucket/object'. This is update syntax from 'setacl' to 'acl set' ?

(https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl#set)

Comment: List of predefined ACLs (private, public-read etc.): https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control

Comment: I tried the acl tactic and updated files just reverted to not shared :(

Answer (score 76):

You can make all objects in a bucket public. Here's the [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public).

> 1. Open the Cloud Storage browser in the Google Cloud Platform Console.
> 2. In the list of buckets, click on the name of the bucket that you want to make public.
> 3. Select the Permissions tab near the top of the page.
> 4. Click the Add members button.
>      The Add members dialog box appears.
> 5. In the Members field, enter allUsers.
> 6. In the Roles drop down, select the Storage sub-menu, and click the Storage Object Viewer option.
> 7. Click Add.
>
> Once shared publicly, a link icon appears for each object in the public access >column. You can click on this icon to get the URL for the object.

Comment: Guys this looks like the answer.  I just tested my bucket permissions. I changed my image and reuploaded and Google Storage didn't screw up the  permissions like it had before I ran this command: gsutil iam ch allUsers:objectViewer gs://[BUCKET_NAME].  Just in case you're wondering Amazon is still in lead on making things like this easy.  Wow way too much learning curve to do the same on GS.

Comment: This should be the correct answers cause there can be unintended effects using gsutil if you don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 63):

When you run: `gsutil -m acl set -R -a public-read gs://bucket` you define public read for all the objects currently in your bucket, but when you upload new files they wont be public by default.

What I found is that is worth to define a bucket default acl as public-read `gsutil defacl set public-read gs://bucket`

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately this works only on a top level bucket and can't be used on a folder within a bucket. The other answer works even on a folder.

Comment: `gsutil defacl set public-read gs://bucket` works with all future files including those within subdirectories. Ignore Plastly Grove's comment.

Answer (score 21):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be by using a console.

Click on "Edit bucket permissions"

[image]

Enter `allUsers` in Add Members.
Then `Select Role` > `Storage` > `Storage Object Viewer`

Attention! This will give read permission to all the people on the internet to all the objects in that selected bucket.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Current (Oct/2017) documentation about Hosting a Static Website found [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) points to:

`gsutil acl ch -r -u AllUsers:R gs://bucket-name`

Where the `-r` does the recursive trick and `-u AllUsers:R` gives the public read access.

Comment: This also works for sub directories, e.g. `gsutil acl ch -r -u AllUsers:R gs://bucket-name/dir-name`

Comment: If that directory has a lot of files, then adding a `-m` will make it after -- `gsutil -m acl ch -r -u AllUsers:R gs://bucket-name/dir-name`

Answer (score 10):

### Apr, 2022 Update:

**You can allow all users to read files in your bucket.**

For example, in **Bucket details**, click **"PERMISSIONS"** then **"ADD"**:

[image]

Then, type **"allUsers"**:

[image]

Then, choose **the role "Storage Legacy Object Reader"** so that all users can read files:

[image]

Then, click **"SAVE"**:

[image]

Then, you will be asked as shown below so click **"ALLOW PUBLIC ACCESS"**:

[image]

Finally, you can allow all users to read files in your bucket:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To copy and paste on Erik's behalf, this worked consistently for me:

> Making groups of objects publicly readable
>
> To make all objects in a bucket publicly readable:
>
> CONSOLEGSUTILREST APIS Use the gsutil iam ch command, replacing
>   [VALUES_IN_BRACKETS] with the appropriate values:

```
 gsutil iam ch allUsers:objectViewer gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make all objects in a public range, this link has more information: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public

If you can't, in your console, log into your bucket and click "Edit bucket permissions" - Enter allUsers in Add Members. Then Select Role > Storage > Storage Object Viewer