# How do I create a public image in Google Container Registry (GCR)?

Tags: google-container-registry

I use GCR to store my team's private docker registry.  I have a docker image that I want to make publicly visible so that multiple projects can use it / share with customers / etc.

How do I make a docker image public within Google's Container Registry?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1) Create an empty cloud project to house the public registry

2) Push something to the registry (so the bucket gets created)

```
docker push gcr.io/{PROJECT_NAME}/{IMAGE_NAME}
```

3) Make all future objects in the bucket public:

```
gsutil defacl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://artifacts.{PROJECT_NAME}.appspot.com
```

4) Make all current objects in the bucket public (eg, the image you just pushed):

```
gsutil acl ch -r -u AllUsers:R gs://artifacts.{PROJECT_NAME}.appspot.com
```

5) Make the bucket itself public (not handled by `-r`!):

```
gsutil acl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://artifacts.{PROJECT_NAME}.appspot.com
```

6) upload more images if desired

Thanks to [How do you make many files public in Google Cloud Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371376/how-do-you-make-many-files-public-in-google-cloud-storage) for providing some of the breadcrumbs here.

Comment: What if you only want to make a single image public, not all of them?

Comment: Ian, I believe that's not possible today.

Answer (score 4):

Google Cloud Registry (GCR) now allows you to easily do this through the Console. Click on "Settings" on the left panel, and change the Visibility to Public.

---

[image: GCR Visibility Settings]