# How to share entire Google Cloud Bucket with GSUTIL

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

Is there a command using GSUTIL that will allow me to share publicly everything in a specific Bucket? Right now, I'm forced to go through and check "share publicly" individually on EVERY SINGLE FILE in the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this is:

`gsutil -m acl ch -u 'AllUsers:R' gs://your-bucket/**`

will update ACLs for each existing object in the bucket.

If you want newly created objects in this bucket to also be public, you should also run:

`gsutil defacl ch -u 'AllUsers:R' gs://your-bucket`

This question was also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371376/how-do-you-make-many-files-public-in-google-cloud-storage) but the answer recommends using `acl set public-read` which has the downside of potentially altering your existing ACLs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$> gsutil acl ch -g All:R -r gs://bucketName
```

gsutil is the command-line utility for GCS.

"acl ch" means "Modify an ACL."

"-g All:R" means "include read permissions for all users."

"-r" means "recursively"

and the rest is the path.

If you have a whole lot of files and you want MORE SPEED, you can use -m to mean "and also do this multithreaded!", like so:

```
$> gsutil -m acl ch -g All:R -r gs://bucketName
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of the command line options involved! Cobbling all this together from Google's relatively opaque documentation is a pain!

Comment: If it helps in the future, the gsutil command line itself has pretty good documentation. For example, the command `gsutil help acl ch` will give you quite a bit of information on how to change ACLs, including a couple pages of examples.

Comment: Yep! I looked at it! Unfortunately 99% of the cases and examples applied to strange access scenarios that don't apply to a simple website like I'm trying to host on there. Could I have figured this out? Sure. But it probably would have taken several hours of staring at the docs and possibly jacking up my site trying to get it to work.