# Flutter Web how to serve file assetlinks.json for Android App Links verification

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, firebase-hosting

I am deploying a **Flutter Web App** on **Firebase Hosting**.

And a **Flutter App on Android**.

To use App Links that redirect to my Android application, I need to verify the App Links serving the file `assetlinks.json` on the web at `https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json`

How can I make the file available, without 3XX redirects, from my domain, that is Flutter deployed on the web with firebase hosting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is enough to add the `.well-know` folder and the file to the `web` folder of your Flutter project.

And to change the `firebase.json` adding headers and rewrites entries.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/web",
    "appAssociation": "NONE",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/.well-known/assetlinks.json",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": "application/json"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/.well-known/assetlinks.json",
        "destination": "/.well-known/assetlinks.json"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

build and deploy again and the file is now accessible!

Thanks for the easy guide to
https://blog.bam.tech/developer-news/universal-links-firebase-hosting-and-flutter-web

Comment: How would it be for another server? like for example Amazon amplify? I cant find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Hosting automatically generates `assetlinks.json` and `apple-app-site-association` files when they are requested. It doesn't require any extra configuration.

You just need to make sure that your app details (package, SHA256 certificate fingerprints, etc.) are correctly setup in the [Project Settings](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/general) and make sure that in your `firebase.json` the property `appAssociation` is set to `"AUTO"` (or omitted, as `AUTO` is the default value).

Example `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "appAssociation": "AUTO",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrite-dynamic-links

Answer (score 0):

Don't mess up the path of your well-known folder.

It should be placed in: build/web
and not just in web.

Answer (score -1):

If I am not mistaken, Firebase stores files in a so called bucket.
The bucket can be directly exposed to the internet or you can use the API to pull the file you need and put it somewhere public on your domain:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files

To see how to publish files in a gloud bucket, here is a good answer:

[How do you make many files public in Google Cloud Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371376/how-do-you-make-many-files-public-in-google-cloud-storage)

Be aware the method described provides public access, so make sure you only expose what you want.

Comment: The problem is not to store the file, but to make it public from your domain, without redirections, when the domain is serving a Flutter Web application.

Comment: If you change the DNS Records to point to cloud storage, then the website is no longer accessible.

Comment: I linked to how to expose it, it does not redirect like that. One can server the website from the same bucket with some limitations. Maybe I misunderstood your questions, it is not totally clear to me. seems you got a good answer.

Comment: You can only serve a static website and you have to reserve the domain to it. Flutter Web is not static and the domain where it is running is the one that needs to be verified, so it cannot be used for cloud storage. But thanks.